# NSTableCellView transparent background

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecellview

In my custom NSTableCellView I override `-(void)drawRect` this way (I do this because I have **pattern image background** of `NSWindow`. I need to show only `NSLabel` in cellView):

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor clearColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

and I get this result, it makes whole `NSWindow` transparent:
[image]

I want result like [VOX mac app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vox/id461369673) do (Look at red eclipse, you see cellView is transparent with parent background image):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem:
I used [MMScroller](https://github.com/phaibin/MMScroller) library (please read it's setup process), with some tricks in xcode:
I checked off **Alternating Rows** in tableView **Attributes Instector**. Then, just setting tableView background color to clearColor in **Attributes Inspector** did the job.

[image]

Comment: _tableView.usesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors = NO;

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways you can change the color of cell.
1) Implement delegate:-

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(id)cell 
  forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn     
    *)tableColumn 
     row:(NSInteger)row
```

And then on the basis of that exract cell value and use `setBackgroundColor` api.

2) second ways you can use `preparecellcolumn` api of tableview which will return cell value and then set `backgroundcolor`.

Comment: I have already an instance of cell, because i use custom cell class. I set setBackgroundColor for layer, but doesnt work.

Comment: Are you getting the value inside the cell correctly check that??

Comment: Oh is it then can you paste your code, i need to check how you are setting.

Comment: In `-(id)init` of `CustomTableCellView` method i have `self.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor].CGColor;`, it doesn't work.

Comment: It is mac app. I tried your solutions, actually preparecellcolumn is used for cell based table cells, but I'm using view based.